# Setting up padding for websites in mobile devices

Tags: iphone, css, mobile, padding, media-queries

I had finished this website a while ago but something happened to it and I've now spent all day fixing it and getting it back from scratch as my backup wasn't correctly done. I don't quite understand what it's doing as I've done this technique on many other websites with no troubles, maybe I've looked at this website too long?

[Here is the website](http://ambergoodwin.com/barnett). I'm wanting to put some space on the left and right hand side, however I dont just have one container as I was needing the dark grey bar at 100% of the screen and always under the banner no matter where it was. So there are 4 "containing" divs that I want to have the space. I've placed soem CSS3 media queries in but now I'm getting a gap to the right. I was thinking it was because my background mages are going all the way across but they set at 100% so I'm just not understanding whats going on. It's somethign simple, I'm not seeing it right now..

This is what I have for the media queries

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {

#header, #banner, #main, #footer-widget-area { padding: 0 2em 0 2em; }

}
```

This is what t looks like on my iPhone

[image]

Any advice is helpful and appreciated.

Comment: @ambrealsweb did u get it what i am talking about it.........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into the `viewport` meta tag.  If you were to add the code to your page's `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1100">
```

That would force the iPhone's viewport to render 1100px wide.  The default viewport on an iPhone is 980px, so your page was implying that 100% width was 980px and not the true content's width.

Viewport can be tricky, here's some more info on it:

[Viewport meta tag for non-responsive design](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/viewport-meta-tag-for-non-responsive-design)

Answer (score 0):

I checked the live site, looks like the issue is down to only 3 pixels of extra space on the right. I also noticed a line-break in the nav menu. It looks like changing the smartphone media query to the following will resolve the last issues:

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {

#header, #main, #footer-widget-area { padding: 0 1em 0 1em; }
#banner { padding: 0; }
#header-right { width: auto; }
#access .menu-header { width: auto; }

h4 { font-size: 1.4em; line-height: 1em; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**How about this:**

```
#wrapper { padding:0 2em; margin:0 auto; overflow:hidden; height:auto; }
#header, #content, #stuff, #etc { margin:0;padding:0; }
#inside stuff { whatever else; }
```

Wrap the `#wrapper` around your outermost `DIV` (right after `<body>` and close before `</body>`).

Unless your plan is to position some elements outside of the 2em padding region, I can't imagine why this would not be a more efficient solution to your problem.